# Outlook Add-In manual load > Not a valid Office Add-In

Tags: outlook, vsto, office-addins

I am working on an Outlook Add-in which works perfectly when loaded from the registry but it seems impossible to load it manually. When trying from the Outlook File > Options > Add-Ins > "Manage -> Go..." and manually select the dll or Vsto file, I receive the message "MyAddIn is not a valid Office Add-In".
I tried with admin right on the machine.
Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add windows registry keys before. See [Registry entries for VSTO Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/registry-entries-for-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2019) for more information.

If you want to add and load your add-in manually make sure the assembly you point implements the `IDTExtensibility2` interface. Otherwise, you will end up with an error message. In the case of VSTO add-ins, you may try to point to the .vsto file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As described, I tried the VSTO and the dll but both give me the error message. I have not found any other way than using the registry.